# Formula to return values into a number of cells based on another cell's value.

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

If I have a cell (A1) value is "2" (set value)
& another cell (A2) value is "4" (number of cells in 1 column i want the set value to appear in)

How do I return the values in B1:B4 to all be "2"?

Comment: Do you have a formula in B1:B4 now? What is it?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated, VBA answer**

Under the Developer tab (if you don't have it, go to Options, Customize Ribbon, and check it) insert a Command Button from the ActiveX section.

Place the button, right click, View Code. Type this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Call Rawr
End Sub
```

Then, still in the VB environment, click Insert, Module. In your new module:

```
Sub Rawr()

Dim i, x, cap As Integer

cap = [A2]
x = [A1]

[B1].Select

For i = 0 To cap - 1
 ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = x
Next i

End Sub
```

You'll probably want some additional code to clear column B for when you have new parameters. Add another button with this code:

```
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

**Original Answer**

It sounds like you're asking how to make the first *x* rows in column B equal to *y*, where *x* is A2 and *y* is A1 - is that right?

There's isn't a way to populate empty cells with values like this with a formula - you'd likely want to use a VBA approach.

If you're comfortable with having formulas in column B that simply *look* blank until needed, place this in B1, and fill it down:

```
=IF(ROW()<=$A$2,$A$1,"")
```

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't really see any fx solution w/o these blank cells.  Appreciate the help though. VBA it is. Thanks.

Comment: Wasn't sure if you had a VBA solution already (and were searching for alternates) or were in need of one.

Comment: Got one, always searching for alternates though.  Thanks!